# Diagonal matrices whose trace equals $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, trace

In linear agebra, is there a special name to matrices $M$ of the form

$$M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & a_{22} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{nn} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $\text{Trace}(M) = a_{11}+a_{22}+\ldots+a_{nn} =1$ and $M$ is a diagonal square matrix with entries $0 \leq a\leq 1 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Moreover what are some basic or interesting properties that these matrices exhibit? I'm looking for any general interesting known things like properties of its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)),... Any insights or interesting remarks are appreciated!

Comment: Trace equal to 1 means the coefficient at $\lambda^{n-1}$ of the characteristic polynomial is equal to 1, that's it. Also since your matrix is diagonal, the characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-a_{11})\dots(\lambda-a_{nn})$.

Comment: Because the matrix is diagonal, there are no repeated factors in the minimal polynomial (even if there are repeated factors in the characteristic polynomial)

Comment: Any diagonal matrix with at least one non zero entry be scaled to one of these matrices. I suspect all of the interesting properties will just come from the fact they're diagonal.